# Why does this form submit on click of the submit button

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geid = function(x) {
        var element = document.getElementById(x);
        return element;
     }          


function submitForm(){
var password = geid('password').value; 
var passwordConfirm = geid('passwordConfirm');

//THIS IS OF HIGH IMPORTANCE THAT THIS CONFIRM PASSWORD MATCHES
//WILL NEED TO VALIDATE IT IN THE PHP AS WELL>
else if (password == ""){
    registerMessage.innerHTML = "Please enter your Password.";
    return false;  
}
else if (passwordConfirm == "") {
    registerMessage.innerHTML = "Please confirm your password.";            
    return false; 
}

else if (passwordConfirm != password) {
    registerMessage.innerHTML = "Your passwords don't match.";          
    return false; 
}
else {
     registerMessage.innerHTML = "Taking you to your profile, please wait a moment...";
     document.forms['registerform'].submit();
}
}

   <form method="post" action="register.php" id="registerform" onsubmit="return submitForm()">


     <label for="password" class="registerLabel">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="registerText" /> <br />

     <label for="passwordConfirm" class="registerLabel">Confirm Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" class="registerText" /> <br />


        <div class="submitMessage">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="registerButton cleangray" /><br />
            <div id="registerMessage"><?php echo $error ?></div>  
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </form>
```

Comment: To make this a good question, you should explain why you think the form should not be submitted. **A code dump is not a question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't start with `else if`; you need to start with `if`

```
if (password == ""){
    registerMessage.innerHTML = "Please enter your Password.";
    return false;  
}
```

That's preventing any of your validation code from running and just submitting the form using the standard submit mechanism.

This also isn't the best way to approach the validation. Rather than return at each error, you could build up a string of messages and report them all back in one go. That way the user knows everything that's wrong — your current method will only ever set one message.

Comment: To be more specific, this parse error prevents the function from running so no `return false` gets invoked; however, the form submission still proceeds because this mechanism is not coupled to Javascript.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I was just updating my answer as you were writing that comment :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Cheers for the edits — sleepy Friday morning.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have error in JavaScript, you are using `else if` without defining `if` first. Because of this error all JavaScript code fail.

Change

```
else if (password == ""){
```

to

```
if (password == ""){
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/Zs3km/

BTW in your code HTML is within `<script>` tag, not sure if its your mistake just here. You have to close `<script>` tag before `<form>` tag is opened.